# IsNullOrWhiteSpace extension method in .Net 4?

Tags: .net

Is there an extension method for IsNullOrWhiteSpace defined in .Net 4?

I have used this extension method before, but I can't find it, and I'm starting to wonder if I was using a custom extension at the time without realizing it.

Comment: You might have used a custom extension somebody wrote in .NET 3.5 where `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` wasn't available yet like I found my code doing today ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an extension method but a `static` method of the [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

[Look here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So you need to write:

```
string s = "123";
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
{
}
```

You can always write you own extension:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string s)
    {
       return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s);
    }
}

string s = "123";
if(s.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I knew about that class, but I have definitely used an extension method for this in the past.  It was quite handy, because I could just call `"".IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` or `null.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` and it would work just the same.  (Because extension methods still run on a null reference).  It must have been a custom extension that was part of the libraries I was using at the time, and I didn't realize it.

Comment: Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities has an extension method for IsNullOrWhiteSpace on strings.

Answer (score 6):

You probably had a reference to WebGrease.dll.  In the Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities namespace, there is an IsNullOrWhiteSpace() extension method on string.

```
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;

"".IsNullOrWhiteSpace(); //This compiles
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an extension method, it's a [static method of `String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

```
"".IsNullOrWhiteSpace()       // Error!
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("") // Correct
```