# Difference between IsNullOrWhiteSpace() extension method vs string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()

Tags: c#

We can check if a string is null or whitespace using 2 ways:

```
var name = "";
name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();
```

or

```
var name = "";
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name);
```

Is there any drawback by using one method instead of the other?

Edit:
I'm using ABP and the extension method comes from them (which I didn't notice). The implementation is as follow:

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string str)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str);
}
```

Now knowing that, I notice that there's not much difference between those two ways of checking for null or whitespace.

Comment: what's the definition of your extension method?

Comment: `name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace();` -- that is something you've written: it's not included in the runtime. The runtime guidelines recommend not putting extension methods on primitive types

Comment: There is no such extension in regular .Net libraries. It is possible you use some library that brings it in (like suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928612/isnullorwhitespace-extension-method-in-net-4). Make sure to [edit] the question to clarify where this method come from, ideally including source code. Note that since method is unlikely to have any interesting logic the question may be closed as "opinion-based" even if you resolve missing information part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is a built-in static method, whereas `name.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is a custom extension method that you need to (manually) create.

Your first example is not valid for a default string. You would have to manually create the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is a Extension, you wrote it in your class or framework because you want to do other things in addition to the basic tasks(IsNullOrWhiteSpace).
and Way two(IsNullOrWhiteSpace) for .Net

How to write this Extension is as follows

```
using System;

public static partial class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The string to test.</param>
    /// <returns>true if the  parameter is null or , or if  consists exclusively of white-space characters.</returns>
    public static Boolean IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this String value)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's recommended and good practice to use the built-in types `string`, `bool` and so on rather than using the classes from the `System` namespace.

Comment: @ewerspej sure, but remember that "good practice" is always an _opinion_, no matter who's publishing it. It's perfectly valid to use `String` instead of `string`.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, that's correct. It wasn't meant as negative criticism, it was supposed to be a constructive hint. Using the built-in types has advantages over using the classes, such as avoiding type redefinition, not having to use the namespace, shorter code and keyword highlighting, just to name a few. Microsoft even added an IDE warning to Visual Studio for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0049. It's still an opinion and matter of choice, but there's a good reason you find this recommendation in some popular .NET books.